# How to put multiple files in file browse

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

APEX ORACLE

So i have a problem when i drag and drop files when i put one file and again open and put another last file only stays not 2 of them example:

[image]
[image]

So i want to have both .txt files test A and test b

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn the **Allow multiple files** property ON?

If you did, then you'll have to drag & drop **all files** at once. If you add them one-by-one, you'll always have just that one - last - file.

Comment: Yes i did use Allow multiple files property so it only works for drag and drop? but what if my files are not in the same folder ? im thinking from user perspective i cant asume they will put them before in same folder then drop them..

Comment: Well, that's the way it currently is (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

When you enable **Allow multiple files**, this only means the user is allowed to select, or drag-and-drop, multiple files, *at one time*. The files they select will all be loaded into the item, replacing anything that was there before.

If you need to save the files so that the user can upload more files, you need to add a dynamic action (on the Change event) to immediately upload and save the files instead of waiting for the user to submit the page; that way, when they select more files later, the first set are already uploaded.